# How to add a custom field to a custom segment type

Tags: netsuite

I have created a custom segment (cost unit) and would like to add for each value the cost center it belongs to, so it is restricted on data entry. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

On the Cost Unit Custom Segment, set "Filtered By" to "Cost Center"/"Department".  For each line/value set the "Filtering".  Refer to Suite Answer [43334](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43334/kw/43334) and [43778](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43778/kw/43778) for more information.

Comment: Thanks this helped. I overlooked basic functionality...